# How do I shift the graph to the left side of the screen?

Tags: react-native

```
<BarChart
  data={data}
  width={Dimensions.get('window').width}
  height={300}
  chartConfig={{
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    backgroundGradientFrom: 'white',
    backgroundGradientTo: 'white',
    decimalPlaces: 0,
    color: (opacity = 0) => `rgba(90, 90, 90, ${opacity})`,
    style: {borderRadius: 0,},
    propsForBackgroundLines:{stroke:"#ffffff"},
    barRadius: 16,
    fillShadowGradient: 'blue',
    fillShadowGradientOpacity: '5'
  }}
  style={{
    marginVertical: 8,
    borderRadius: 16,
    padding: 5
  }}
  verticalLabelRotation={45}
  withHorizontalLabels={false}
/>
```

Hi all, the above is my code and how my graph looks like. I am currently using react-native-chart-kit. However, i am lost as to how to move the graph to my left, since i don't need the y axis labels. Any help would be grateful, thank you.

[Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIIXx.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `paddingRight: 0` inside the style props to remove the padding altogether. The code might look like

```
<BarChart
  {...}
  style={{
    marginVertical: 8,
    borderRadius: 16,
    padding: 5,
    paddingRight: 0

  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `paddingRight: 0` in style will solve this issue.

```js
<LineChart
  data={}
  chartConfig={chartConfig}
  bezier
  withHorizontalLabels={false}
  withDots={false}
  withVerticalLabels={false}
  withInnerLines={false}
  style={{
    paddingRight: 0,
  }}
/>
```